# Service Worker Installed and Activated, But No Fetch Event

Tags: javascript, fetch, service-worker, sw-precache

I have a service worker generated by sw-precache that I'm registering on a page. The install and activate events both fire and complete successfully, files are cached, and the registration on the page completes successfully, however the fetch event never fires. From what I've read, this is usually caused by requests being targeted outside of the scope of the service worker, however the scope is the application root (which I can see from the registration object returned from the register call), and all sources are contained within. I've tried different ways of referencing the files, but the behavior is always the same. I also get the same results in Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas as to what, other than scope, would cause fetch to not fire?

Update: The code involved is particularly unhelpful...

```
  if("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("ServiceWorker.js").then(function(registration) {
      console.log("Service Worker installed successfully.", registration);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Service Worker registration failed: " + err);
    });
  }
```

The service worker is generated by sw-precache and too long to place here in its entirety, but here are the relevant listeners:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return setOfCachedUrls(cache).then(function(cachedUrls) {
        return Promise.all(
          Array.from(urlsToCacheKeys.values()).map(function(cacheKey) {
            // If we don't have a key matching url in the cache already, add it.
            if (!cachedUrls.has(cacheKey)) {
              var request = new Request(cacheKey, {credentials: 'same-origin'});
              return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
                // Bail out of installation unless we get back a 200 OK for
                // every request.
                if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error('Request for ' + cacheKey + ' returned a ' +
                    'response with status ' + response.status);
                }

                return cleanResponse(response).then(function(responseToCache) {
                  return cache.put(cacheKey, responseToCache);
                });
              });
            }
          })
        );
      });
    }).then(function() {

      // Force the SW to transition from installing -> active state
      return self.skipWaiting();

    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  var setOfExpectedUrls = new Set(urlsToCacheKeys.values());

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.keys().then(function(existingRequests) {
        return Promise.all(
          existingRequests.map(function(existingRequest) {
            if (!setOfExpectedUrls.has(existingRequest.url)) {
              return cache.delete(existingRequest);
            }
          })
        );
      });
    }).then(function() {

      return self.clients.claim();

    })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("Fetch!");
  if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
    // Should we call event.respondWith() inside this fetch event handler?
    // This needs to be determined synchronously, which will give other fetch
    // handlers a chance to handle the request if need be.
    var shouldRespond;

    // First, remove all the ignored parameters and hash fragment, and see if we
    // have that URL in our cache. If so, great! shouldRespond will be true.
    var url = stripIgnoredUrlParameters(event.request.url, ignoreUrlParametersMatching);
    shouldRespond = urlsToCacheKeys.has(url);

    // If shouldRespond is false, check again, this time with 'index.html'
    // (or whatever the directoryIndex option is set to) at the end.
    var directoryIndex = 'index.html';
    if (!shouldRespond && directoryIndex) {
      url = addDirectoryIndex(url, directoryIndex);
      shouldRespond = urlsToCacheKeys.has(url);
    }

    // If shouldRespond is still false, check to see if this is a navigation
    // request, and if so, whether the URL matches navigateFallbackWhitelist.
    var navigateFallback = '';
    if (!shouldRespond &&
        navigateFallback &&
        (event.request.mode === 'navigate') &&
        isPathWhitelisted([], event.request.url)) {
      url = new URL(navigateFallback, self.location).toString();
      shouldRespond = urlsToCacheKeys.has(url);
    }

    // If shouldRespond was set to true at any point, then call
    // event.respondWith(), using the appropriate cache key.
    if (shouldRespond) {
      event.respondWith(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
          return cache.match(urlsToCacheKeys.get(url)).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
              return response;
            }
            throw Error('The cached response that was expected is missing.');
          });
        }).catch(function(e) {
          // Fall back to just fetch()ing the request if some unexpected error
          // prevented the cached response from being valid.
          console.warn('Couldn\'t serve response for "%s" from cache: %O', event.request.url, e);
          return fetch(event.request);
        })
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Needless to say, "Fetch!" never shows in the console.

Comment: Please post relevant code if you'd like our assistance.

Comment: Is this the only service worker on that scope? and the scope is `/` I believe? and the `activate` event fires and logs on the console If you place a log statement under the event listener for `activate` just before `clients claim`?

Comment: Also what do you see under `service workers` tab on the applications menu on the dev console -- assuming you use chrome

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat The scope is the root of the application (may or may not be the root of the server), yes. I tried putting logging statements at the beginning of install, in the caching part of install, just before skipWaiting, at the beginning of activate, and just before clients.claim. All of those fired correctly. There is also a service worker shown for the expected scope in dev tools, and it's shown as activated and running.

Comment: Hmm.. Usually a `fetch` is not fired if there are multiple workers for the same scope and a different worker wins the fetch race. that , or, if the worker itself, is not active. which you are saying is not the case here. trying to think of something else that may go wrong... but nothing in the code you posted should create this issue

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat I wouldn't expect the code itself to be an issue, since, like I said, it's generated by sw-precache. If that were the problem, there'd most likely be a known issue on that repo for it. The only odd thing in the app (with regards to loading) is that it includes modules by appending script tags to the head, but even static script/style includes aren't triggering fetch.

Comment: True. Also, a disclosure: I have yet to use precache. I have however used service workers by themselves, handwritten.Could you possibly include your url structures. One depicting the url at which service worker resides, and two, the general static asset urls that you navigate to - to see how your uri components are separated basically. I am still of the belief, that you just might have a very trivial scope issue

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat using "~/" to represent the application root, as opposed to the server root "/", the service worker exists directly at "~/service-worker.js" (the scope is set to this as well), and one of the page's resources, for example, is at "~/Content/site.css". All of my static content is in either "~/Content/" or "~/Scripts/"